# can i use magmi to automate inventory with suppliers data

Tags: magento, automation, scheduling, inventory, magmi

Hi Can anybody tell me that is it **possible** to automate the inventory with **suppliers** data with **magmin**.
Actually i have 3 suppliers and they update there inventory regularly and i have to do all through csv , is there a way that i can automate all process ,means

> regularly update the data

with suppliers data automatically or at

> **scheduled** time.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.

Magmi CLI interface is made for this, coupled with a cron , if you have the right profiles already defined (one per provider) , automating is a no-brainer.

Magmi is already able to get csv from remote locations, so configure one profile per vendor with adequate plugin parameters.

See : [Magmi Command line](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_command_line)

Comment: Dweeves, i am planning to automate magmi with the help of curl but when i hit url from browser it is giving error to login but i am trying to do seamless integration, can you help on this.